# Plotting data accurately (without lines) texture or ortho projection or something else?

Tags: opengl, matrix, graph, orthographic

I have some scatter graph data that I want to plot accurately. The actual data is a grid of data.

If I do I simply put all the graph data into a vbo and draw it as points, I see lines between my data points.

I believe this is to do with the conversion into screen space. So therefore I need to apply a projection matrix.

Im sure I want Ortho projection but currently I seem to have a bug in my ortho matrix generation:

```csharp
void OrthoMatrix(float[] matrix, float left, float right, float top, float bottom, float near, float far)
        {
            float r_l = right - left;
            float t_b = top - bottom;
            float f_n = far - near;
            float tx = - (right + left) / (right - left);
            float ty = - (top + bottom) / (top - bottom);
            float tz = - (far + near) / (far - near);

            matrix[0] = 2.0f / r_l;
            matrix[1] = 0.0f;
            matrix[2] = 0.0f;
            matrix[3] = tx;

            matrix[4] = 0.0f;
            matrix[5] = 2.0f / t_b;
            matrix[6] = 0.0f;
            matrix[7] = ty;

            matrix[8] = 0.0f;
            matrix[9] = 0.0f;
            matrix[10] = 2.0f / f_n;
            matrix[11] = tz;

            matrix[12] = 0.0f;
            matrix[13] = 0.0f;
            matrix[14] = 0.0f;
            matrix[15] = 1.0f;
        }
```

But I can't work it out. My shader is:

gl_Position =  projectionMatrix * vec4(position, 0,  1.0);

and my data is plotted like (subset)

```c++
-15.9   -9.6
-15.8   -9.6
-15.7   -9.6
-15.6   -9.6
-16.4   -9.5
-16.3   -9.5
-16.2   -9.5
-16.1   -9.5
-16 -9.5
-15.9   -9.5
```

The image on the left is correct (but with lines) and the image on the right is with ortho:
[image]

A colleague has suggested to first put the data into a bitmap that conforms to the plot region and then load that. Which to some degree makes sense but it seems like a step backwards. Particularly as the image is still "stretched" and in realty we are just filling in those gaps.

**EDIT**
I tried a frustrum projection using glm.net and that works exactly how I want it to.

The frustrum function seems to take similar paramaters to ortho.. I think its time I went and read up a bit more about projection matrices!

If anyone can explain the strange image I got (the ortho) that would be fantastic.

**EDIT 2**
Now that I am adding zooming I am seeing the same lines. I will have to either draw them as quads or map the point size to the zoom level.

Comment: By the looks of it, your manually built orthographics projection matrix is transposed; OpenGL uses column major indexing, but your matrix is row major indexed. That would also explain the strange looks of your "ortho" projection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "lines" you see are actually an artifact of your data samples locations becoming coerced into the pixel grid, which of course involves a rounding step. OpenGL assumes pixel centers to be at x+0.5 in viewport coordinates (i.e. after the NDC to viewport mapping).

The only way to get rid of these lines is to increase the resolution at which points are mapped into viewport space. But then your viewport contains only that much of pixels, so what can you do? Well the answer is "supersampling" or "multisampling", i.e. have several samples per pixels and the coverage of these sample points modulates the rasterization weighting. Now if you fear implementing this yourself, fear not. While implementing it "by hand" is certainly possible it's not efficient: *Most (all) modern GPU come with some kind of support for multisampling*, usually advertised as "antialiasing".

So that's what you should do: Create an OpenGL context with full screen antialiasing support, enable multisampling and see the grid frequency beat artifacts (aliasing) vanish.

Comment: The sampling could also be done by first putting the data into a texture. 

Not that keen on using anti-aliasing as it would pollute the data.

presumably If the points where increased to a size that mapped to the gap that would work? Is that what you mean by viewport space? In this case could I solve it by matching the gap in the data... The worry is I don't want the points to overlap as later they will have a specific color

Or I could work out how to draw it as a triangle list and use flat shading?

Comment: I forgot to mention I am less concerned about "filling the gaps" now that the lines are more uniform (thanks to the projection matrix).

Comment: @chrispepper1989: There is a fundamental difference between OpenGL "points" and pixels. A point is a geometrical primitive that the rasterized value may actually by "adjusted" by the OpenGL implementation in any way it sees fit. The specification gives implementations some leeway in the exact results, as long as a given chain of operations always leads to the same results down to the pixels. But two distinct OpenGL implementations actually may differ significantly. What is it you're trying to achieve in the end?

Comment: effectively all the points, with their own colour applied do form "an image" hence why its seems logical to put them into a bitmap / texture. However there are 2 caveats here. 1.) it is graph data and I don't want to distort that to much by using a actual image.
2.) the colours change in realtime based of many factors. Each X,Y has multiple values, I convert this value (floating point range) to an intensity and scale it across a colour scale (like a point by point heat map). The user can select 1 or more values, adjust the colour scale etc.